# Why is this ajax code not working?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm trying to submit a form with ajax with the code below, but apparently doesn't seem to work.

Any suggestion to fix this problem?

```
$(".dialog-set-new-message").on('keyup', '.ctxtareados', function(b){
    if(b.keyCode == 8){return false;}
    if(b.keyCode == 13){ 
    // 
    $("#submit_new_message_cbox").submit(function(eventmsg){
    $(".loader-wait-gif-con").fadeIn(500);  
    eventmsg.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
    url: "https://www.mypage.com/success/set_new_cbox_message.php",     // Url to which the request is send
    type: "POST",             // Type of request to be send, called as method
    data:  new FormData(this),    // Data sent to server, a set of key/value pairs representing form fields and values 
    contentType: false,           // The content type used when sending data to the server. Default is: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
    cache: false,         // To unable request pages to be cached
    processData:false,        // To send DOMDocument or non processed data file it is set to false (i.e. data should not be in the form of string)
    success: function(data)     // A function to be called if request succeeds
    {
    $(".dialog-new-chat-open-con").load("../success/refresh_new_cbox.php", function(){
    $(".loader-wait-gif-con").fadeOut(500);
    $(".con-sub-nav-chat h3").html("Messages updated.");
    $(".con-sub-nav-chat").css("display", "block");
    $(".con-sub-nav-chat").fadeOut(7000);
    $(".all-msg-new-chat-box").animate({scrollTop: $("#sldum").offset().top}, 1000);
    });
    $('#submit_new_message_cbox')[0].reset();  
    }
    });
    });
    //  
    }
    });
```

--FIXED--

I Added a input[submit] in the php file and modified the code as follow:

PHP Code added:

```
<input style="visibility: hidden;" id="submitnmcbox" type="submit">
```

JS Code Modified (same as above):

```
$(".dialog-set-new-message").on('keyup', '.ctxtareados', function(b){
if(b.keyCode == 8){return false;}
if(b.keyCode == 13){ 
$("#submitnmcbox").click();
}
});

//Set new msg chat
$("#submit_new_message_cbox").on('submit', function(eventmsg){
$(".loader-wait-gif-con").fadeIn(500);  
eventmsg.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
url: "https://www.dudoby.com/success/set_new_cbox_message.php",     // Url to which the request is send
type: "POST",             // Type of request to be send, called as method
data:  new FormData(this),    // Data sent to server, a set of key/value pairs representing form fields and values 
contentType: false,           // The content type used when sending data to the server. Default is: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
cache: false,         // To unable request pages to be cached
processData:false,        // To send DOMDocument or non processed data file it is set to false (i.e. data should not be in the form of string)
success: function(data)     // A function to be called if request succeeds
{
$(".dialog-new-chat-open-con").load("../success/refresh_new_cbox.php", function(){
$(".loader-wait-gif-con").fadeOut(500);
$(".con-sub-nav-chat h3").html("Se han actualizado los mensajes.");
$(".con-sub-nav-chat").css("display", "block");
$(".con-sub-nav-chat").fadeOut(7000);
$(".all-msg-new-chat-box").animate({scrollTop: $("#sldum").offset().top}, 1000);
});
$('#submit_new_message_cbox')[0].reset();  
}
});
});
//
```

Comment: What kind of error did you encounter?

Comment: @pciang Console shows 0 errors kinda weird.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are using `FormData()` constructor wrongly. According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData/FormData), `FormData()` constructor accept HTML DOM form element (*optional*). Example:

```html
<form name="myForm">
  <input type="text" name="text_field_1" value="test1" /><br /><br />
  <input type="text" name="text_field_2" value="test2" /><br /><br />
  <input type="text" name="text_field_3" value="test3" /><br />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var myForm = document["myForm"];
  var formData = new FormData(myForm);
  console.log(formData.get("text_field_2")); // returns "test2"
</script>
```

Comment: but I have implemented the same ajax code in other functions and works perfectly. I dont think so.

Comment: Ah, sorry, didn't see that `$.ajax()` call is in `.submit()` scope.

Comment: Can you show us the code for those other functions you implemented this same ajax code in?